# How to install library from source code, without any config nor Makefile?

Tags: c, linux, zip, installation, libraries

Sorry for what is likely a simple question -- still getting a handle on Linux.

I've been attempting to install the 'FreeMODBUS' library, however judging from the website, it is somewhat outdated. The download link leads to nowhere, however the source code is still accessible via Sourceforge as a .zip download. In the past I've only dealt with libraries that come via .tar, however the bigger issue is that there seems to be no config, makefile nor README detailing the installation process.

Additionally I tried including all of the source code and header files supplied within my Eclipse project. I was hoping that this would be the lazy man's solution to all of my problems -- or at the very least I could compile the .so file myself -- however I'm still getting 'undefined reference to [Function]' errors. From what I understand this is a linking issue. To the best of my knowledge all inclusions are correctly set up.

Is this library deprecated, or is there a step to the process that I'm overlooking? Thanks!

---

Some superfluous project information:

I'm using modbus for a C project. The network is ideally going to be setup so that a number of modbus enabled devices are configured on a single daisy chained RS-485 hub -- therein containing all our modbus communications to a single comm port in a rather complex system.

The problem however is that popular open source modbus library, 'libmodbus', doesn't appear to lend itself to this configuration. In order to instantiate a modbus node instance, it requires the comm port to be passed, as opposed to the unit's modbus id.

Comment: I'd be inclined to take the incomplete source and broken links at the project web site as good reasons to avoid this project.  *At best*, it is unsupported.

Comment: It looks like it wasn't meant to be used as a traditional Unix library, but instead simply compiled and linked in with your system-specific C code. There's a Makefile in demo/LINUX, for instance, that references virtually all the source files. That doesn't mean it can't be made into a library, of course.

Comment: Great, thanks for the confirmation!